# "not a Parquet file (too small)" from Presto during Spark structured streaming run

Tags: hive, hdfs, apache-spark-sql, parquet, presto

I have a pipeline set up that reads data from Kafka, processes it using Spark structured streaming and then writes parquet files to HDFS. Downstream clients of the data query is using Presto configured to read the data as Hive tables.

`Kafka --> Spark --> Parquet on HDFS --> Presto`

In general this works. The problem arises when a query happens while the Spark job is running a batch. The Spark job creates a zero-length Parquet file on HDFS. If Presto attempts to open this file in the course of processing a query, then it throws an error:

`Query 20171116_170937_07282_489cc failed: Error opening Hive split hdfs://namenode:50071/hive/warehouse/table/part-00000-5a7c242a-3e53-46d0-9ee4-5d004ef4b1e4-c000.snappy.parquet (offset=0, length=0): hdfs://namenode:50071/hive/warehouse/table/part-00000-5a7c242a-3e53-46d0-9ee4-5d004ef4b1e4-c000.snappy.parquet is not a Parquet file (too small)`

The file is indeed zero bytes at this time, so the error is strictly correct, but this is not the behavior I want for the pipeline. I would like to be able to continuously write in to the appropriate HDFS folders, without disturbing the Presto queries.

The Spark scala code for the job looks like this:

```
val FilesOnDisk = 1
Spark
  .initKafkaStream("fleet_profile_test")
  .filter(_.name.contains(job.kafkaTag))
  .flatMap(job.parser)
  .coalesce(FilesOnDisk)
  .writeStream
  .trigger(ProcessingTime("1 hours"))
  .outputMode("append")
  .queryName(job.queryName)
  .format("parquet")
  .option("path", job.outputFilesPath)
  .start()
```

The job starts at the top of the hour, :00. The file is first visible on HDFS as a zero-length file at :05. It is not updated until it is written completely at :21, just before the job finishes. This makes the table effectively unusable from Presto 25% of the time.

Each file is only a little over 500kB, so I wouldn't expect the physical writing of the file to take very long. From my understanding, Parquet files have their metadata at the end of the file so someone writing bigger files would have even more trouble.

What strategies have people used to integrate Spark structured streaming and Presto while working around this Presto error?

Comment: Hi @Dave_Cameron, I have a very similar problem. I'm reading a topic from Kafka and writing it to Parquet, although I'm not using HDFS. When I try to read the parquet file from Spark and the stream is running, I get "Unable to infer schema for Parquet". It must be specified manually;" which I guess it's because I'm trying to read the same parquet while I'm writing it. 

I've seen here on the spark user mailing you've written this
https://github.com/davcamer/spark/commit/361f1c69851f0f94cfd974ce720c694407f9340b

Is that working for you? Did you find any other solution?
Cheers

Comment: @redsk I had the same problem! It would be great if you asked this as a separate question and I could show some code around the solution. The very quick answer is that you need to specify the schema on the DataStreamReader. Check out this method: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/DataStreamReader.html#schema-org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to persuade Presto (or Presto team) to ignore empty files, but that wouldn't help, as the program writing the file (here: Spark) will eventually flush partial data and the file would appear partial, non-empty and not well formed, thus leading to an error as well.

The approach preventing Presto (or other programs reading the table data for that matter) from seeing partial file would be to assembler the file in *different* location and then *atomically* move the file into the correct location.

Comment: It took me a while to accept that this is truly the correct (and maybe only) way to approach the problem. I have accepted that now, and so your answer too.